# Trouble creating POJO using GSON

Tags: java, android, gson

I seem to be having trouble creating POJO(Plan Old Java Object) from JSON using GSON. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) to the T but I am still getting a null object. Here's my code:

JSONHandler.java

```
public class JSONHandler 
{
    private Gson gson; 
    private InputStream is; 
    private Reader reader;
    private TripList tripList; 
    public JSONHandler(InputStream is)
    {
        this.is = is;

        gson = new Gson(); 
        reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        tripList = gson.fromJson(reader, TripList.class);
    }
    public Gson getGson() {
        return gson;
    }
    public void setGson(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }
```

TripList.java

```
public class TripList 
{
    @SerializedName("Line")
    public String line;

    @SerializedName("CurrentTime")
    public int currentTime; 

    public List<Train> Trips; 

}
```

Train.java

```
public class Train 
{
    @SerializedName("TripID")
    public String tripID; 

    @SerializedName("Destination")
    public String dest; 


    public List<Prediction> Predictions; 

}
```

Prediciton.java

```
public class Prediction 
{
    @SerializedName("StopID")
    public int stopID;

    @SerializedName("Stop")
    public String stop;

    @SerializedName("Seconds")
    public int seconds;
}
```

blue.json

```
{
    "TripList":
   {
        "CurrentTime":1342032950,
        "Line":"Red",
        "Trips": [
             {
                  "TripID":"R982ECC1E",
                  "Destination":"Alewife",
                  "Predictions": [
                          {"StopID":"70094","Stop":"Ashmont","Seconds":370}
                   ]
             },
             {
                  "TripID":"R982ECC78",
                  "Destination":"Ashmont",
                  "Note":"Big Red",
                  "Position":
             {"Timestamp":1342032834,"Train":"1809","Lat":42.38725,"Long":-71.11894,"Heading":185},
                "Predictions": [
                        {"StopID":"70067","Stop":"Harvard Square","Seconds":36},
                        {"StopID":"70069","Stop":"Central Square","Seconds":260}
                  ]
               }
           ]
     }
}
```

The JSON format will follow [this](http://www.mbta.com/uploadedfiles/Description.pdf) paradigm. GSON doesn't throw an error when cannot parse something correctly, it just returns a null value which is irritating. Is there something wrong with the format or the way I handled the java data objects? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JSON knows how to read a `public List<Train> Trips;` as the genericity is compile-time only.

see https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples for more details, but basically, i think you need to specify a TypeToken for you elements

Comment: also, it seems related to http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=170

Comment: You're wrong, the type parameter for `List<Train>` gets captured in the class `TripList`, so no`TypeToken` is needed.

Comment: what i don't see is how gson will know it is a list of train, given that this information is not kept at runtime.

Comment: But it is, see `Field.getGenericType()` where you get the field via `Trips.class.getDeclaredField("Train")`. Normally, it gets erased, but here it's a part of the class definition (if it was a type parameter of the class, then it'd get lost, but it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue we ran up against type erasure - you might want to look into implementing generics (if there will be more List elements in your code) or else explicitly telling Gson what type of type you want to serialize

Comment: You're wrong, the type parameter for `List<Train>` gets captured in the class `TripList` and the same holds for the other `List`. Erasure is no problem here as no information gets lost (see `java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType()`).

Comment: You're right - after looking back at my code I saw I needed to implement it when I had a List<ExampleObject> where Profile contained a List<OtherObject> and the type of other object was being lost by Gson

Answer (score 0):

There's a trivial problem: You're reading an object containing TripList:

```
{
   "TripList": ...
}
```

but you tell Gson that you're reading a TripList itself:

```
tripList = gson.fromJson(reader, TripList.class);
```

As `TripList` contains no property named `TripList`, this does what it does: The unknown properties (i.e., "TripList") get ignored while the missing properties (i.e., all members of "TripList" get left at their default value.

So Gson behaves correctly here. I don't know if there's a problem with generics here. If so, the other answers may help.

---

#### Update

There's no other problem there, I've tried it. Just remove the enclosing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising the Lists in each of your model classes.

I.e.

```
public class TripList 
{
    @SerializedName("Line")
    public String line;

    @SerializedName("CurrentTime")
    public int currentTime; 

    public List<Train> Trips = new ArrayList<Train>(); 

}
```